# c# SetIfChanged-Method with Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I have to following C#-code quite a lot:

```
public void UpdateDB(Model.ResultContext db)
{
    Model.Planning.Part dbPart = db.Parts.Where(/*someClause*/).FirstOrDefault();

    //The awkward part
    if (dbPart.Number != Number)
    {
        dbPart.Number = Number;
    }

    if (dbPart.NumberShort != NumberShort)
    {
        dbPart.NumberShort = NumberShort;
    }

    if (dbPart.Designation != Designation)
    {
        dbPart.Designation = Designation;
    }
}
```

It is obviously kind of awkward to check every field and wrap it in `if != then set`
Yes, the check is needed because otherwise the database sees everything as changed columns.

The fields to set are auto-Properties:

```
public class Part 
{
    [MaxLength(36), MinLength(1)]
    public string Number { get; set; } = null!;

    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Designation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

and I don't want to write an explicit setter for every field which of course could do the checking before setting.
So what I thought of is some Method ´SetIfChanged´ which is called like this to make the code more readable and less error-prone:

```
//Options 
dbPart.SetIfChanged(dbPart.Number, this.Number);
dbPart.SetIfChanged(dbPart.Number = this.Number);
dbPart.SetIfChanged(Number, this.Number);
```

I think something like that is possible with expressions or lambdas but to be honest... I'm stuck with the syntax of declaring and calling such a method

Anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, C# is lacking a number of things to help you with this (e.g. property `ref`s or extension methods on reference objects), but you can use Reflection to help with this. It is likely to be quite slow, however.

With a method that takes a lambda, you can write a set method:

```
public static void SetIfDifferent<T>(Expression<Func<T>> getterFnE, T newVal) {
    var me = (MemberExpression)getterFnE.Body;
    var target = me.Expression;
    var targetLambda = Expression.Lambda(target);

    var prop = me.Member;
    var oldVal = getterFnE.Compile().Invoke();
    if ((oldVal == null && newVal != null) || !oldVal.Equals(newVal)) {
        var obj = targetLambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        prop.SetValue(obj, newVal);
    }
}
```

This would be used like:

```
SetIfDifferent(() => dbPart.Number, Number);
SetIfDifferent(() => dbPart.NumberShort, NumberShort);
SetIfDifferent(() => dbPart.Designation, Designation);
```

This would be slow because of the need to compile the `Expression` trees and use `DynamicInvoke`. One way to speed it up would be to pass in a setter and getter lambda instead, but that leads to as much duplication as your original code.

If you would be willing to pass the object and name of the property instead, you could use:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

public static void SetIfDifferent2<TObj, TField>(this TObj obj, string fieldName, TField newVal) {
    var prop = typeof(TObj).GetProperty(fieldName);
    var oldVal = prop.GetValue<TField>(fieldName);
    if ((oldVal == null && newVal != null) || !oldVal.Equals(newVal))
        prop.SetValue(obj, newVal);
}
```

Which you could use like:

```
    dbPart.SetIfDifferent2(nameof(dbPart.Number), Number);
    dbPart.SetIfDifferent2(nameof(dbPart.NumberShort), NumberShort);
    dbPart.SetIfDifferent2(nameof(dbPart.Designation), Designation);
```

Unfortunately, it requires repeating `dbPart` unless you are willing to just put in the field name (e.g. `"Number"`) but that will cause runtime errors if the field changes.
You could also cache the `PropertyInfo` instead of looking it up with `GetProperty`, but that is generally pretty fast and caching probably isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really need checking (lets say at the end you want to know if anything has been changed or not) you can use Reflection and loop through properties. but in your case no check is needed.

take this for instance:

```
  if (dbPart.Number != Number)
    {
        dbPart.Number = Number;
    }
```

true) if the value is different you are setting the new one

false) means that the new value and the old value are the same, so doesn't hurt to set it again

If you want to know if anything has changed at the end:

```
bool changed = false;
var type = dbPart.GetType();
foreach(var (PropertyInfo)pi in type.GetProperties()
{
    if(pi.GetValue(dbPart) != newValue)  
    {
         changed = true;
         pi.SetValue(dbPart, newValue);
    }
}
```

or you can do something like:

```
bool changed = dbPart.Number != Number || dbPart.Designation != Designation;
dbPart.Number = Number;
dbPart.Designation = Designation;
```

Comment: yes, your're right. Sadly I forgot one thing: I need to know at the end if anything actually has changed, so my method sould return a has-changed-flag

Comment: I think this still dosn't work because I had to call this for every fields newValue, but anyway, I think I really missed one thing that made my whole question pointless, so thank you for your help and SORRY

Comment: no problem, please also check my final edit on answer.